# Hyphenated adjective vs non-hyphenated adjective (when saying the entity has the thing)

Tags: grammar, hyphenation, compound-adjectives

I am still a bit confused about what the senses of these two nouns are: 1. White-tiled counter 2. White tiled counter. Does the one with no hyphen actually exist?

Comment: In this case, it doesn't make much difference to the meaning (a counter covered in white tiles, or a tiled counter which is white - unless you envisage the second  as being white-painted wood with tiles just on the top).

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot, kate :)